# How to Fetch custom column value from Sharepoint 2010 user group

Tags: sharepoint-2010, web-parts

I have created an user group in SP 2010 and i have added one custom column to it, from the list settings.
How to get the custom column value in web part?
EDIT:
My custom column is District. I want to return that column value in visual web part application. 
To return group users i use this code
`List<SPUser> users = SPContext.Current.Web.SiteGroups["PDO Owners"].Users.ToList();`
 [image]

Comment: I do not understand what you mean when you write that you have added a custom column to a user group. Can you provide screenshots of what you have done and what you are trying to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

I assume you mean you created a custom property for the user profile as in my opinion you cannot add extra columns to user groups. You can get the values through the ProfileManager object doing something like this:

```
//GET THE USER PROFILE MANAGER
SPServiceContext sc = SPServiceContext.GetContext(site);
UserProfileManager userProfileManager = new UserProfileManager(sc);

//GET A PROFILE FOR A USER
UserProfile profile = userProfileManager.GetUserProfile("i:0#.f|fbamembershipprovider|myfbauser");

string propertyvalue = profile["propertyinternalname"].Value.ToString();
```

Depending on the type of field, you will have to use something else than ToString (eg for a managed metadata field i think you should use TaxonomyFieldValue, etc...)

Comment: In Sharepoint 2010 foundation i dont have Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles.dll, and i cannot use UserProfileManager